# I want articles.html page to appear whenever I go to /articles or /articles/ but I get 403 because my directory listing is turned off

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

this is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
*.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' *.gstatic.com data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
*.google-analytics.com www.googletagmanager.com *.googleapis.com data:; connect-src
'self' *.google-analytics.com *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com data:; img-src * data:;
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
```

I just don't understand how to assign a html page to a sub directory without getting a 404 or 403 error. if the page to be accessed is at /articles/ and I have a link /articles, it automatically redirects to me to /articles/ and tells me I am forbidden to access the page with a 403 error. Because of this, even Google has crawl the page, hurting the SEO of my website. Please help!

Comment: Well, you explicitly prevent that the request gets rewritten to the html page. Your first condition _explicitly_ says: if a directory by that name exists, then do _not_ apply the following rewrite rule.

Comment: I don't really know how htaccess works in the first place. I just want to make sure that the server checks for files with the same name as the directory and replace the directory indexing with the custom page. If a file with the same name as the directory doesn't exist, I need to bring in a 403/404 error. Please guide me by providing the updated code I could possibly use in my htaccess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]
```

The rewriting module need to be loaded into the http server, obviously, and you need to take care that distributed configuration files are considered at all (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation for that).

---

UPDATE

The 40 status you receive back *may* be an effect triggered by the `DirectoryIndex disabled` above. If a request hits a directory with no html next to it as you described there would be then indeed you will get a 403, since you explicitly deny directory listings.

Apart from this requests with a training slash may cause issues, so here is a version which rewrites suh requests too:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$ /$1 [END]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I replaced my code (the first 4 lines) with this and now the website says 403 forbidden (even the index page). Any idea on why that's happening?

Comment: I cannot tell you why you get a 403, but that has nothing to do with above code. There is nothing that generates a 403 in there.

Comment: It might be that you created a file permission issue when uploading files. The error log file of your http server will tell you.

Comment: I just replaced the first 4 lines with with this code. I edited the htaccess file in the cpanel itself. I am getting very confused using htaccess. Every time I change even a bit of the contents of the file, a major change takes place when accessing it. Please help me solve the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, the `DirectoryIndex disabled` might trigger a 403 if a request hits a directory with no matching html file beside it. That is what you asked for, though.

Comment: I added an update to the answer considering such issues.

Comment: Replacing the code (the first 4 lines) with your updated code returns a 404 for me. I just want to try to explain my problem one last time. When someone requests for a url which has the same name as the directory, I want the server to check if such file exists and send that instead of 403 (since my directory listed is disabled) and if no such file is there, I want a 403 to appear. Ex: /mac/ should automatically redirect to /mac (the file without extension) but if I go for /mac2/ (whose file doesn't exist), I want to bring up a 403. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: I am looking a solution similar to this (except for the fact that I'm working on html): https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess

Comment: That is what above code should do, precisely. If it does not work as expected you will have to find out why things don't work instead of hopping from code snippet to code snippet. So: have you made sure distributed configuration file are considered at all? How? Does the rewriting show _any_ effect or none at all? What does your http server's error log file reveal? What does turning on rewrite logging show up as additional information?